# glmmTMB segmentation fault

Tags: r, environment, mixed-models

My model is of the form:

```
m1 <- glmmTMB(counts ~ fixed1*fixed2 + (1|random/nested_random) 
+ offset(log_total_counts), data = long_data_frame,
verbose=FALSE,family="nbinom2")
```

Here are the first six rows from the 115 rows of long_data_frame:

```
fixed1   fixed2   random    nested_random   counts    log_tot_reads_orig
0        0        1         1               643       12.89582
1        8        2         6               585       13.67509
2        25       3         11              846       13.94209
3        75       4         16              755       13.93056
4        0        5         21              1428      13.65672
6        8        6        26               1566      13.64421
```

The model runs to completion on my Mac laptop (OS 10.13.4). However, I need to port this analysis to the local cluster, since I need multiple 300,000 runs of these glmmTMB tests. I therefore installed glmmTMB on the cluster using

```
install.packages('package_name', dependencies=TRUE)
```

There are no complaints when I run:

```
library(glmmTMB)
```

But when I run the one individual example of the model on the cluster, I get the following error:

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address (nil), cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: retape(set.defaults = TRUE)
 2: MakeADFun(data.tmb, parameters, map = mapArg, random = randomArg,     profile = NULL, silent = !verbose, DLL = "glmmTMB")
 3: eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame())
 4: eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame())
 5: with.default(TMBStruc, MakeADFun(data.tmb, parameters, map = mapArg,     random = randomArg, profile = NULL, silent = !verbose, DLL = "glmmTMB"))
 6: with(TMBStruc, MakeADFun(data.tmb, parameters, map = mapArg,     random = randomArg, profile = NULL, silent = !verbose, DLL = "glmmTMB"))
 7: fitTMB(TMBStruc)
 8: glmmTMB(copy ~ week * conc + (1 | pool/cell) + offset(log_tot_reads_orig),     data = subset(copy_raw_sub_l, copy_raw_sub_l$id == i), verbose = FALSE,     family = "nbinom2")

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
```

Here is some information on the cluster:

```
Sys.info()
                             sysname                              release 
                             "Linux"         "2.6.32-696.18.7.el6.x86_64" 
                             version                             nodename 
"#1 SMP Thu Jan 4 17:31:22 UTC 2018"                             "login2" 
                             machine                                login 
                            "x86_64"                            "bob" 
                                user                       effective_user 
                           "bob"                            "bob"
```

Here is info on glmmTMB:

```
installed.packages('glmmTMB')
     Package LibPath Version Priority Depends Imports LinkingTo Suggests
     Enhances License License_is_FOSS License_restricts_use OS_type Archs
     MD5sum NeedsCompilation Built
```

The "MD5sum Needs Compilation Built" looks wrong? Almost surely this is a problem with the environment on my cluster, I guess? I would be very grateful for suggestions on how to fix this issue, or pointers on what could be modified or upgraded in the cluster, which I could then suggest to my local administrators. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My wonderful cluster administrator filed a report about this issue with glmmTMB on GitHub:

https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/369

We were informed that apparently the issue had been dealt with previously:

https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/232

The solution suggested by my cluster administrator was to create a file called

```
$HOME/.R/Makevars
```

with the following content:

```
CXX = g++
CXXSTD = -std=c++11
CXXFLAGS =-m64 -O3 -fPIC
```

I then ran:

```
install.packages("TMB",dependencies=TRUE,type="source")
```

I got the following error message:

```
ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘path/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5’ for modifying
Try removing ‘path/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/00LOCK-TMB’
```

I removed the miscreant directory as suggested. I then ran once again:

```
install.packages("TMB",dependencies=TRUE,type="source")
```

follwed by:

```
install.packages("glmmTMB",dependencies=TRUE,type="source")
```

I then ran:

```
library(glmmTMB)
```

and ran the model described in the question. The joy of victory overwhelmed my senses as covariates and log likelihoods ran down the screen, in parallel with my tears of happiness.